# How to check iPad have iPadOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipados

How can I programmatically check the **iPad** have **iPadOS** or **iOS**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`systemName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620054-systemname?language=objc) keyword to identify the OSname of the device

**systemName**

> The name of the operating system running on the device represented by the receiver.

so finally you need to use

**Swift**

```
 let getOSName = UIDevice.current.systemName
 print("device OS Name =\(getOSName)")
```

**Objective C**

```
 NSString *getOSName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];  
 NSLog(@"device OS Name = %@", getOSName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What do you want to determine with that test?

That said: make a version number check. 13.x and above is iPadOS, 12.x and below is iOS.

In Swift at runtime, this would be

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    // ipad os
} else {
    // ios
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gereon for the reply, Actually I want to know where Apple mention any method for this or not?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html